# WCF JSON Service with no DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm writing a WCF service where I need to consume a Json message, but I don't want to maintain data contract classes for it. The idea is to consume it via an input stream or string and then serialize it and pass it along to another endpoint. I can read it in, but the input is always null. Maybe there's a way to use a dynamic DataContract that would work, not sure. I can send in a serialized text Json string just fine, but I don't want the customer to just send me the raw json message so I can pass it along serialized to another endpoint. Is this possible w/o the DataContract?

If the message is sent in via application/json, the sMessageIn is always null

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,   
   UriTemplate = "/test"
         )]
  String RestMessage(String sMessageIn);
```

Input Json sent over the wire via Postman using JSON (application/json) mode.

```
  {
    "test": {
      "Code": "t",
      "Type": "cr"
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you sending this over the wire?

Comment: I'm testing w/ Postman using JSON (application/json) and sending above input test json. It goes through, but sMessageIn = null. I'm hoping this will work w/o the consumer side having to send in a serialized data stream as (text/plain). The service just needs to consume the inbound raw JSON message, serialize it and forwarded it on to another endpoint off the DMZ. I don't want any DataContacts on the service side to maintain since the service could be consuming different Json messages. I hope this is possible w/ some dynamic type of DataContract if I even need one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a deep read but it demonstrates a way to create a custom message formatter which may work for this scenario --> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. there is one solution for it. you can use this class as your input and then pass it your dynamic value to it. but unfortunately  you cant pass the nested JSON object to it.

```
[Serializable]
public class WebServiceDictionary : ISerializable
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Entries { get; }

    public WebServiceDictionary()
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public WebServiceDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
            Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value.ToString());
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entry in Entries)
            info.AddValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
```

then you define your method like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  
   UriTemplate = "/test"
         )]
  String RestMessage(WebServiceDictionary sMessageIn);
```

now you can pass any thing you want. some thing like this:

{
      "Code": "t",
      "Type": "cr"
    }

you can access to the parameters in a Dictionary object like this:

```
sMessageIn.Entries[Code]
```

Comment: Actually, this is a good solution for basic Json messages, but it won't work for me since it won't support nested json messages which I have to deal with. I'm really surprised that Microsoft left a hole here that can't be solved unless you use DataContracts. Thanks for helping w/ this though.

Comment: you are welcome dear @Wildview. but remember things are little different in wcf. they have to support both rest and soap together.

Comment: Yeah realize that. I will check this off as an answer though since it could help someone that doesn't use json nesting. Thanks again!